# Why was my answer deleted by a moderator on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, link-only-answers, specific-answer

I answered a question about URL Rewriting in asp.net. The question URL is

[how to remove the extension .aspx of first login page on my web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19296043/how-to-remove-the-extension-aspx-of-first-login-page-on-my-web-application/19296132)

My answer to the question was pretty simple.

> "Use the URL Rewriting dll available from http://urlrewriter.net/ for removing extensions from the url."

I am no way affiliated with this open-source URL Rewriter. I have used it in many projects and found it really good for URL Rewriting.

I believe it was a valid answer and pointed the person in the right direction.

Is this how the moderators treat community members of Stack Overflow?

Comment: It's a link-only answer. If the link breaks the answer is useless. Although there's no clear-cut rules on link-only answers, be aware that link-only answers are subject to deletion at any time.

Comment: Its not a link only answer. It shows the name of the open source dll which can be downloaded from multiple sites.

Comment: Moreover, link-only answers often tend to be _spam_.

Comment: It seems like a moderator complaint is never complete until it ends with some sort of editorial lashing-out. It's especially funny how well-written and well-explained this appears at first that it almost makes the editorialization seem like an afterthought: "Oh yeah, I forgot to say something demeaning."

Comment: You can't delete an answer just because it may tend to be a spam. The moderator needs to actually verify it and then delete it.

Comment: To be fair though, the deleted answer actually delivers a solution to the problem, different from the surviving answer, which is completely useless. Flagging that one as "not an answer" now

Comment: @user1039119: How, pray tell, would you expect us to do that?

Comment: @perhaps Pekka: Yeah that's true.

Comment: Verifying a spam link could mean clicking on it, which is *exactly* what the spammer wants.  An off-site search could work as well, but moderators shouldn't dedicate time to that.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, just by clicking the link and checking if it's valid link or not. If one can't do that, there is no point being a moderator.

Comment: Even this question got two negative votes. Ha ha. Policing everywhere.

Comment: @user1039119: Oh, OK. I guess I will tender my resignation in a bit. /s

Comment: Yeah man. I mean, we pay those moderators a huge salary. Checking out every weird link that comes across their path is the least we should expect from them

Comment: Yeah. You can delete a correct answer but cannot verify a link is valid or not. Great Moderation.

Comment: There are more issues with link only answers than just invalid links. This has been discussed many times before. What you could do is combine the link with an actual answer that you got through that link - that would have a good chance of going through

Comment: @user1039119 And guess what, with Bolt tendering resignation shortly, you have a chance to apply for the moderator position.

Comment: It's not our job to police whatever random links you may throw into an unsubstantiated answer.  We have enough work with just moderating this site, thanks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, You can delete an answer but can't check the authenticity of a link. Great. What about the other answer on that question? Was it a substantiated answer? Was it specific? Still it was not deleted.

Comment: Why do I care about someone else's site?  Why should the user have to click on a link to another site to get his answer, because you were too lazy to provide an actual answer?

Comment: There is no way around to do URL Rewriting in .net version 3.5 and lower without using a third-party dll. The user needs to download it for url mapping. Everybody may not be using the most updated version of .net.

Comment: I have seen plenty of answers pointing to codeplex.com website to download a particular dll as accepted answers.

Comment: I really don't want to discuss this further. It seems as if a group of moderators who are completely not interested in receiving feedback has taken control of the entire site. Its not turning productive at all. Even this question received 6 negative votes. I think this was a pretty valid question though with a pretty valid answer.

Comment: @user1039119 Those answers probably weren't good either - just that the site has so much activity and noise that a lot of things fall through the cracks. It really is up to you to actually substantiate your answer. There's no takeover conspiracy here, even though you might feel like you were treated badly by having your answer deleted. It wasn't a good answer though and in general answers like this - if they don't immediately appear to be spam - are the kind that should be downvoted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your answer resembles spam.

It was promoting a resource. It's a one-line answer which doesn't even provide any guidance on how to *use* that resource - there's a *severe* lack of effort to provide a useful answer here. There are, additionally, features already built into ASP.NET to deal with the problem, so an external resource isn't necessary.

For a long-term user, these factors together set off loud alarms that you might just be using this as an excuse to advertise a tangentially related resource, whilst putting in no effort to provide a genuinely useful answer.

#### How do you avoid getting your answer deleted in the future?

Next time you link to an external resource, make your answer *actually a substantial answer*. Put some effort into your response and actually provide guidance on using that resource. Sure, they can use this library - but *how?* What do they do with it? What features do they use? What is the library even for? What is it about? Why would they want to use this?

"Here, use this library" opens up more questions than it answers. If that is all your answer consists of, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are 6 points from being free to comment everywhere.

> [image]

[image]

Wait some minutes/hours/few-days and you can provide useful solutions without using the Answer box to give *one* link. Those kind of answers don't fit this network quality standards and are deleted for this reason.

Check the guide [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had 52 points. The downvotes on that answer brought me down to 44. Ha ha.

Comment: lolo, that's what happens... give quality answers and you'll reap up votes...