# "show N more comments" cannot be clicked on mobile browser (when not logged in)

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

Perhaps related to [Dynamic “add / show N more comment(s)” cannot be clicked when not logged in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191280/213634), this question is different in that I **can** click the comment link on my desktop when not logged in, but **not** on my iPhone. (iOS 6.1.3, built-in Safari browser).

As can be seen here, the text "show 9 more comments" is in the link colour, signifying that this can be clicked just as the name of the user who posted the last question is - but while his name *can* be 'clicked' leading to his profile as expected, the text "show 9 more comments" is not active:

[image: show 9 more comments not clickable]

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201614/213634) is the question I've used as an example.

I can see this both on an iPhone and on a Windows phone, but *not* on an iPad.

I haven't tried to reproduce while being logged in on either of the phones.

Comment: @BenCollins I *just* saw you had marked the other, similar, question status-complete and was just about to try to repro. But it still persists, the link is inactive.

Comment: This seems to be a different, mobile-specific problem, although it does behave very similarly.

Comment: This was mentioned again on http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/573/the-link-show-1-more-comments-doesnt-work-on-the-mobile-site

Comment: +1. I just got this on the "show more comments" on the Q @ http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17070/i-worked-for-a-company-affiliated-with-a-very-publicly-failed-project-should-i

Comment: Same here with iPhone 5s, iOS 7.0.4. When you click on a link that directs you to the last comment (e.g. `#comment72384723-whatever`), the website actually shows all comments. But, it still displays a non-working "show 5 more comments" link.

Comment: I was about to report this and found this question. Testing in Chrome incognito mode and switching to the mobile version of the site I see that clicking the X more comments link *does* in fact load more comments. But the link confusingly remains making it look as though nothing changed. Then clicking on it gives the irrelevant "commenting requires 50 rep" notice.