# Mobile site comment notice inconsistent with desktop site

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-answers, mobile-web

I was browsing Meta on my phone and noticed that [one of my *deleted* posts (link is 10k only)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207705/216322) had some new comments:

[image: mobile-site show 5 more comments]

I tried to click to display the comments but nothing happened. This was repro'd on Android 4.2.2 (Chrome 31) and on mobile IE 10. I figured it might be a browser issue, and so I switched to my desktop machine. There, I saw a different message:

[image: desktop-site comments disabled on deleted locked posts]

So which is correct, the mobile site or the desktop site? My guess is the latter. By the way, both sites display six existing comments.

Slightly related: [“show N more comments” cannot be clicked on mobile browser (when not logged in)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201627/show-n-more-comments-cannot-be-clicked-on-mobile-browser-when-not-logged-in)

The difference here is that I *am* logged in. (But then again it could just be that there are not actually any more comments to display.)