# show n more comments does not change text when clicked

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

Similar to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201627/show-n-more-comments-cannot-be-clicked-on-mobile-browser-when-not-logged-in) bug and mentioned in the comments:

When logged in clicking works and also fetches the comments, but opposed to the desktop client, the text of the link stays at "show n more comments"

I have reproduced this behaviour on Android 4.2.2 with Chrome 31.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't repro so I'll assume it has been fixed in March by @m0sa as part of ["show N more comments" cannot be clicked on mobile browser (when not logged in)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201627/show-n-more-comments-cannot-be-clicked-on-mobile-browser-when-not-logged-in).