# Add comment and Show X more comments do not work on mobile when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, mobile-web

This might be related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201627/241700) but the add comment and show x more comment buttons do not work on mobile when not logged in

Images for reference:

[image]
[image]

I have so far tested this in Safari and Chrome on my iPhone

Comment: reproduced, on it

Answer (score 5):

Mobile views needed a bit more localization love. Fix rolling out in build rev `2014.3.3.2008` on meta and `2014.3.3.1415` on sites.

Comment: Wow thanks a bunch! :)